# Basic C Pointers

Tags: c, cs50

For some reason when I try to compile this code in the C program it is giving me back an error. I am trying to print out the actual memory address of variable x. If anyone knows I would appreciate it!

Code:

```
    int x = 7;
    printf("x is %d\n", x);

    x = 14;
    printf("x is %d\n", x);

    int *aptrx = malloc(sizeof(int));
    aptrx = &x;                  

    printf("aptrx is %x\n", aptrx);
```

Error:

```
*pointer.c:12:29: error: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type* 'int \*' [-Werror,-Wformat]
```

Comment: Why are you `malloc`ing memory and then immediately leaking it?

Comment: @Jnuggin: Did you study the documentation for `printf`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Just realised it, will delete my comment. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: oh I see now that I need to use the free function to prevent memory leaks and segmentation faults. Also, in this case, it doesn't make sense to allocate memory since I'm only dealing with memory in the call stack by printf'ing the address?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to have this line in your code if you just want to print the address of **x**.

```
int *aptrx = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

You do not need to allocate memory whenever you create a pointer variable. If you want to point to an existing variable, which you want in this case, you can simply do

```
int *aptrx = &x;
```

Then try to print the address using below line using the format specifier **%p**.

```
printf("aptrx is %p\n", aptrx);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having an error because the format expects an `unsigned int` but the argument is an `int *`.

The manual for `printf` says about the `%x` conversion specifier:

> The **unsigned int** argument is converted [...] to unsigned hexadecimal (x and X)
>   notation.

If you want to print a pointer, you can use the `%p` conversion specifier.

> The **void *** pointer argument is printed in hexadecimal (as if  by %#x
>   or %#lx).

Like this:

```
printf("aptrx is %p\n", aptrx);
```

Comment: `%p` output could be anything, not necessarily hex

Comment: That might refer to the specific system's default compiler only

Comment: In fact there for a null pointer `(nil)` is printed, a 5 character string and of those 5 digits none is a hex digit

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to allocate memory dynamically to create a pointer variable.

```
int *aptrx = malloc(sizeof(int)); //unnecessary
```

Simply, create a pointer variable just like any other variable

```
int *aptrx = &x;
```

To print out the value of the pointer (i.e. address of x), use the format specifier %p or %u:

```
printf("aptrx is %p\n", aptrx);
```